# Evitar que regla .htaccess agregue slash en archivo .xml generado

Tags: php, .htaccess

Había creado un archivo `sitemap.xml` manual, cuando accedía a ese archivo este no me agrega un `slash o /` al final, es decir no sucedía esto: `example.com/sitemap.xml/`

Pero para evitar tener que hacerlo manualmente y realizar cambios constantes, he creado un archivo `PHP` para que me genere ese archivo `sitemap.xml` automáticamente ya listo todo el sistema agregue esta regla que me encontré en la web

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml/?$ sitemap.php
```

En mi archivo `.htaccess` el problema que presento es que esta regla me agrega un `slash o /` al final de tal modo que al acceder al archivo `sitemap.xml` me redirreciona a: `example.com/sitemap.xml/` como puedo evitar que eso suceda, lo que deseo es que pase lo mismo cuando realizaba el `sitemap.xml` manualmente es decir que no se agregaba un `slash o /` al final sino que se mostraba de tal manera:

`example.com/sitemap.xml`

Comment: Esa regla cambia la url `/sitemap.xml/` a `/sitemap.php` pero no esta agregando els `slash` al final, debe ser en otra parte donde se esta haciendo la redireccion que dices. De todas maneras, que resultado es el que deseas obtener? viendo la regla deduzco que quieres redireccionar a `/sitemap.php` pero no me queda claro.

Comment: @JeroniChamorro Lo que hace esa regla es poder ver el archivo `sitemap.php` como `sitemap.xml` el problema es qué, al acceder al archivo `example.com/sitemap.xml` me redirecciona agregando un `slash` al final es decir de tal manera: `example.com/sitemap.xml/` aclaro que no son otras reglas las que cause dicho error dado a qué puedo ingresar archivos fijos sin que se agreguen ese `slash` al final como por ejemplo: `example.com/index.php` entre otros. El resultado esperado es que se muestre en la URL de tal manera: `example.com/sitemap.xml` sin que agregue un `slash` al final `.xml/` de la URL

Comment: Habría que ver el resto de tu .htaccess, seguramente tienes una regla que redirige archivos que no existen.

Comment: Prueba con esta regla: `RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]`. Si te funciona, comenta y trataré de explicarte lo que sucede. En caso contrario, me comprometo a eliminar este comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap\.php [L]
```

Comment: Por favor considera leer [answer]

Comment: Descudia, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Usa esta linea de codigo te ayudará a remover los `slash`

> Nota: Siempre realiza una copia de seguridad de ese archivo.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=permanent,QSA]
```